# This is a compatibility issue with the service workers for the webview of the ios device

Tags: service-worker, progressive-web-apps

This is a question about the compatibility of service worker on ios devices. After testing, safari has good support for service worker after ios 11.3 version,but the Chrome on the same device is not supported.However, webview of the client uses webkit kernel directly,so it can't use this new feature of Progressive Web App.Is there any further solutions to this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is a compatibility issue. Apple (currently) forces you to use Safari on iOS in order to get whatever PWA functionality that is available on iOS. Other browsers on iOS are stuck with appcache.

Comment: Will this compatibility issue be resolved in the future?

Comment: You will have to ask Apple.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at webkit + service workers, and it seems that Apple has decided to not allow service workers to work on custom webkit browsers. Even though Safari can be envoked from a iOS app, there is little more offered in terms of programmable functionality. Webkit gives way more functionality the way Apple offer it (typically XCode + SWIFT). With service workers in addition, hybrid apps would indeed shine. Please ref. Look for instance here: https://webkit.org/blog/8090/workers-at-your-service/